# Using setState to change current value of ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a warning on react, which is because i'm currently updating a state hook from outside a setstate statement. However, i'm not quite sure how to do this otherwise.

```
this.state.iXWeek.current.value = 1
```

This object is in fact, a react ref, which makes it particularly tricky to me

```
iXWeek: React.createRef(),
```

I'm recieving this warning:

> Line 242:11:  Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()  react/no-direct-mutation-state

Dont get me wrong, I understand the issue, but i simply dont know how to fix it. Is there somebody here able to help me out?

Comment: Why are you putting a ref in state?

Comment: Isn't that the way to create a ref for class components? Or am i acting stupid?

Comment: `this.iXWeek = React.createRef()` no state needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put the ref in state.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.iweek = React.createRef();
    }
    // directly set this.iweek.current later on...
}
```